# Issue with Apollo Client POST request - Possibly related to content length header

Tags: javascript, http, graphql

I'm trying to debug an issue that's occurring on our site with using Apollo Client/ GraphQl in Firefox. While the issue occurs in Firefox on my machine I believe it is also occurring for other users in different browsers like Safari.

Specifically what i'm trying to understand is if one of my headers `content-length` on a `POST` request could be causing the issue.

My request seems to work fine when I'm in private browsing mode however in normal browsing i'm getting a null response.

When I compare the two requests side by side, the only issue I can see is a vast difference in the `content-length` value.

The JSON body i'm sending across the 2 different requests is the exact same and looks something like this:

```
operationName: "Checkout"
query: "query Checkout($id: ID!) { node(id: $id) { ... on Checkout { id totalPrice webUrl customAttributes { key value __typename } lineItems(first: 100) { edges { node { id quantity title customAttributes { key value __typename } variant { id __typename } __typename } __typename } pageInfo { hasNextPage hasPreviousPage __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } }"
variables:{
    id:"faw8fa8wfha9w8fh9898h8ahw8hdawf"
    service:"shopify"
    shopifyStoreUrl:"my-store-url.myshopify.com"
}
```

When I have Firefox running normally (where it doesn't work) the `content-length` value is 21. When I run it in private browsing mode (where is does work) the value is 950.

Is it safe to assume here that the request is not sending the entire body when Firefox is running normally and hence the culprit?

Comment: Have you tried to analyse your `header` with something like `wireshark`? Or just try to decode what is in your content. It could be possible that when you are not in "private" - mode that more parameters are sent, which could break API calls.

Comment: incompatible plugin ?